# Creating tuples of images and distributing the tuples into training and testing sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, tuples, namedtuple

I've a simple program that creates a bunch of images. The problem is, they need to be ordered into tuples of three images so that the images in each tuple are kept together when they are distributed to the Train, Validation, and Testing sets (one image is derived from the other two images). I then need that each of these three images (in the respective train, validation, and testing sets)

For example, the images created are labeled as n_m  where "n" is the group/name and "m" is the the image in the group. m varies from 1 to 3 and these three images are to stay together whether in the training, validation or testing set. So for example, the testing set might consist of [17_1, 17_2, 17_3, 82_1, 82_2, 82_3, ... ].

Now I've figured out how to make named tuples (the name = n for each tuple of matrices). I however don't know the correct way to load all of the created images (from the matrices) such that I can associate each image tuple e.g. n_1, n_2, and n_3, with each name n so that I can then break the tuples up into training, testing, and validation sets.

Basically I am wanting to pull in all images from the folder and keep images created from the matrices in a tuple (n_1,n_2, and n_3) together when I distribute them to the training and testing sets. I don't have to do it with the named tuples and am open to suggestions.

```
import warnings
import sys
if not sys.warnoptions:
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os
import random
from collections import namedtuple

def Create_RGB_tuples(List_In):
    res = [(val,val,val) for val in List_In]
    return res

def merge_Lists(ListA, ListB):
    ListA[:len(ListB)] = ListB
    return ListA

def multiplyby255(n):
    m = n*255
    return m

def Create_imagesfromTuple(inputTuple):
    ComputationNumber = 1
    for i in inputTuple:
        print(*i)
        counter = 1
        for p in i:
            print(*p)
            multiplied_list = list(map(multiplyby255, p))
            blank_image_list = [255 for _ in range(width * height)]
            Tuples = Create_RGB_tuples(multiplied_list)
            Outputimagesize = (width, height)
            CM_Image = Image.new('RGB', Outputimagesize)
            CM_Image.putdata(Tuples)
            # Save image to file enumerated by the computation: 1 = Theta1, 2 = Theta2, and 3 = Computed Image from 1 and 2.
            # Then enumerate by the set of tupled images.
            ImageName = str(str(ComputationNumber)+"_"+str(counter))
            CM_Image.save(path + "/{file_name}.png".format(file_name=ImageName))
            counter += 1
        ComputationNumber += 1

    CM_Image.putdata(Tuples)  # Place pixels in the new image.

path = "CM_Images"
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)
NumberofVars = 2;
width= NumberofVars; height = NumberofVars
BooleanFunNum1 = []
BooleanFunNum2 = []

NumberOfComputationSets = 10
for i in range(NumberOfComputationSets):
    BooleanFunNum1.append(random.randrange(0,pow(2,pow(2,NumberofVars))));
    BooleanFunNum2.append(random.randrange(0, pow(2, pow(2, NumberofVars))));

CM_MatrixArr1 = []
CM_MatrixArr2 = []
CM_Final = []


for j in range(len(BooleanFunNum1)):
    Theta1 = list(np.reshape(np.random.randint(2, size=4), (1, 4))[0])
    CM_MatrixArr1.append(Theta1)

    Theta2 = list(np.reshape(np.random.randint(2, size=4), (1, 4))[0])
    CM_MatrixArr2.append(Theta2)

combinedCM_MatrixArr = []
for x,y in zip(CM_MatrixArr1, CM_MatrixArr2):
    combinedCM = []
    for a,b in zip(x,y):
        LogVal = (a == b)
        combinedCM.append(int(LogVal == True))
    combinedCM_MatrixArr.append(combinedCM)

Tuple_of_CMs = []

Tuple_of_CMs = []
for a,b,c in zip(CM_MatrixArr1, CM_MatrixArr2, combinedCM_MatrixArr):
    Tuple_of_CMs.append((a,b,c))

Create_imagesfromTuple(Tuple_of_CMs)


Array_of_named_Tuples = []
Counter = 1
for a,b,c in zip(CM_MatrixArr1, CM_MatrixArr2, combinedCM_MatrixArr):
    Tuple_of_CMs.append((a,b,c))
    ComputationSet = namedtuple("ComputationSet", "Name Theta1 Theta2 ThetaComputed")
    Array_of_named_Tuples.append(ComputationSet(Counter, a, b, c))
    Counter += 1
```

Comment: So, you want to associate 1_1, 1_2, 1_3 to `ComputationSet(Name=1, Theta1=[0, 1, 0, 1], Theta2=[0, 0, 0, 0], ThetaComputed=[1, 0, 1, 0])` , and do the same for rest of 27 images?

Comment: Not quite, I want to be able to get some each tuple of images e.g. 1_1,1_2, and 1_3 to stick together no matter if they are put in the training, testing, or validation sets. that is, I don't want, say 1_1 and 1_3 to go to the training set and 1_2 to go to the validation set.